FastUI Page Event
I need help with PageEvent in FastUI.
I want receive Id in def modal_view from def deliveriy_choice field 'id'
How I can do this?
I have this code
@router.get('/add/delivery', response_model=FastUI, response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def deliveriy_choice(
        session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)
):
    filters = DeliveryFilter()
    deliveries = await Delivery.get_by(session, filters)
    return page(
        c.Heading(text='Добавить', level=2),
        c.Paragraph(text='В базу'),
        c.Table(
            data_model=DeliveryTable,
            data=deliveries,
            columns=[
                DisplayLookup(
                    field='id', on_click=PageEvent(
                        name='server-load',
                        context={'id': {id}'}
                    )
                ),
                DisplayLookup(field='create_at', mode='date'),
                DisplayLookup(field='shop', mode='auto')
            ]
        ),
        c.Div(
            components=[
                c.ServerLoad(
                    path='/mission/delivery/dynamic-content/{id}',
                    load_trigger=PageEvent(name='server-load'),
                    components=[c.Text(text='before')],
                ), ],
            class_name='py-2',
        )
    )


@router.get('/delivery/dynamic-content/{id}', response_model=FastUI, response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def modal_view(
        session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session),
        id: str | None = None
) -> list[AnyComponent]:
    print(id)
    # delivery = await Delivery.get_by(session, filters=DeliveryFilter(id=id))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    return [
        c.Paragraph(text=f'Good'),

            ]

I don't know how I can do this.
What I do wrong? I think something wrong with context={'id': '{id}'}
